# How do I redirect back to a specific show View after submitting a form? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I'm using Laravel to create an online teaching system, I have a rudimentary CRUD system that allows me to create degree paths. When I click on a degree path I'm taken to degrees/{{ degree->id }} and from there I can create modules. When I submit my form however, I don't know how to redirect back to that specific view. I can redirect back to the index page, then access the view and see that the module has been added, but I don't know how to go straight to the degree view.

I'm aware you can manually input the ID, but then what if I wanted to create a module for another degree?

Anyway, here's the store function, where my data is submitted to :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $module = new Module;
  $module->title = $request->input('title');
  $module->description = $request->input('description');

  $module->save();

  return redirect('/degrees');
```

The issue is in the redirect, I need to know how that can transfer me to the route (degrees/{{ degree->id }}), but if I type that out it doesn't understand what ID I actually want and throws an error.

Any advice is welcome, the functionality works, I can see the modules displayed on the degree page just need to know how to get there after submitting the data.

I'm relatively new to web-dev, so if I need to re-do things feel free to tell me I'm probably compounding errors at this point.

Comment: Try `return redirect('/degrees/'.$module->id);`

Comment: What you actually want? redirect back or redirect to an another module

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ is right. But you should use `$module->getKey()`

Comment: @hitler_jr10 redirect back I guess. Once the modules created its displayed on the degree page, you access the create page from a link on the degree page.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return back()->with('success','Submitted successfully');
```

Answer (score 0):

return redirect()->back()->with('success', "success message");